# Angular - invoke function on last element in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

How do i invoke function at last element in the *ngFor iterator. Below is the code i tried but it's invoking infinite times. Is there any way to invoke function at last element?

Thanks for the help

template.html

```
<div class="some-class" *ngFor="let item of items index as i; last as isLast">
   <div *ngIf="isLast">{{callSomeFunc(isLast)}}</div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
callSomeFunc(isLast) {
  console.log(isLast)
}
```

Comment: Your code work as you expected its return `true` two times not infinite.   have you provide proper Array on items?

Comment: Add ngIf="i==isLast" to check whether the index is at last position

Comment: @Gokul, i is index, which is a number. `isLast` is a boolean

Comment: call a function in a *ngFor using *ngIf="isLast" is the worst idea you can think: a *ngFor is evaluated **several times** in life of application. Why don't call the function when you get the values of "items"?

Answer (score 2):

Complementary my comment
if you has a component like

```
<div class="some-class" *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2];let i=index;let isLast=last">
   <div *ngIf="isLast">{{callSomeFunc(i)}}</div>
</div>
```

//In ts

```
callSomeFunc(value:any){
    console.log(value)  //You'll see in console severals 2
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed semicolon in `*ngFor`.

### Solution:

```
<div class="some-class" *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; last as isLast">
  <div *ngIf="isLast">{{callSomeFunc(isLast)}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's calling every time @Saddam, only once i need to call a function.