# How can I scroll to a specified component selector inside ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have multiple components run inside *ngFor on the same page. I want to have several button links on the top of the page which can scroll to the component once clicked.

Here are the codes I am trying to follow.

in html file:

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

and in the ts file:

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

but I don't know how could I reference to each of the component selector

Here are some of my code without implementing the above code yet:

```
//There will be many buttons to link to each of the component.

<button type="button" (click)="scroll()">Click this button to navigate</button>

<div *ngFor="let appdata of appData">
    <app-details [value]="appdata"></app-details>
</div>
```

The 'appdata' is a json variable including attributes like appID (which could uniquely identify the component), title, description, etc.

Please advice how can I reference the components and maybe suggest how to implement it. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to an element  we can use the **window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos)**  function
provided by javascript.

you could do like this

first, declare a variable that refers to the window Object

```
win:Window=window;
```

then define the scroll functionality

```
  scroll(component){
        this.win.scrollTo(0,component.offsetTop);
   }
```

where component parameter points to the  specific element.
and **component.offsetTop** gives the y position of that element.

and in the HTML,

```
   <span *ngFor="let target of  win.document.getElementsByTagName('app-details');let i=index" >
        <button  (click)="scroll(target)"  > Go TO {{i}}</button></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write up something like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let appdata of appData; let i = index;">
    <app-details [id]="i" [value]="appdata"></app-details>
</div>
```

on click of the scroll button, you can write up your TS to focus there:

```
const element = document.querySelector(id); // id of the scroll to element
element.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, wanted to scroll into view after the list was built.  Building off [@Abhishek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952021/2957952) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53803608/2957952).

```
<div *ngFor="let appdata of appData; let i = index;let isLast = last">
    <app-details [id]="'item' + i" [value]="appdata"></app-details>
    <span *ngIf="isLast">{{ scrollIntoView('item' + i) }} </span>
</div>
```

In your typescript file:

```
  scrollIntoView(id: string) {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    element?.scrollIntoView();
  }
```